# What are the differences and similarities between CYC and IBM Watson?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

From what I gathered from Wikipedia, CYC is based on set membership logic. So it would take symbols and create set membership predicates. But how is this different from IBM Watson?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/artificial/comments/4h699c/cyc_and_ibm_watson/